# How to use an array for the field name in a UI component?

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent

How do I set the name of a UI component field to use a nested array rather than just the name?

As an example, I want it to be:

```
<input name="something[field_name]"/>
```

Currently it is:

```
<input name="field_name"/>
```

I've seen the catalog module does this, but this seems to be via a block and not directly in the UI component, which is what I want to do!